# Rails - AJAX window.location redirect not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

In my Rails app, stringified JSON form input is passed to a controller via AJAX - on success, the user is to be redirected to a summary page, but the AJAX redirect doesn't seem to be working...

```
$.ajax({
    url: "report/submission",
    type: "POST",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content"))},
    data: {"report" : reportParameter},
    success: function(response) {
        window.location.href = "/report/summary";
    }
});
```

and the associated controller

```
def submission
    @incomingReport = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(params[:report])

    @newReportIDArray = Array.new

    @incomingReport.each do |x|

        hash = ActionController::Parameters.new(x)

        @new_report = Report.new(report_params(hash))
        @new_report.save

    end
end
```

Everything else seems to work just fine - the data is entered, but the redirect does not trigger.  I've searched all around and it looks like this is the syntax that everyone says to use, but it doesn't seem to work for me.  I'm sure that I am doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what.

**Editing to clarify problem/solution**
During a chat with @Jonathan and @Kumar, I noted that  `window.open("/report/summary")` did work correctly - @Jonathan suggested that I just try `console.log(window.location)` before the ajax call, and to my surprise, the script from a function from elsewhere in my app was logged.  Big shocker now - THE FUNCTION WAS CALLED `location()`!!!  Renaming the function and then restarting the app in a new window solved the problem.  Learn from my mistake, kids - don't name a function `location()`.

Comment: At what point does it stop working ? Did you add `byebug`s in your code to make sure you were returning anything and not just crashing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby isn't my first language but it doesn't look like you're sending a response back. Try `return`ing something or `puts`ing. Look up how to do that with rails, a proper response. Maybe `render json: [success: 200]` or something like that. Maybe it's irrelevant. In any case, if it's not working try changing `success` for `complete` and log out the response to debug. The complete will always fire, but success won't always.

Try this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json do
    render json: {
      success: 200
    }.to_json
  end
end
```

In your AJAX setup, add `"datatype": "json"`.

You could improve the response to conditionally send a failure like `success: 500` if something went wrong.

You don't really need `respond_to` block here because you're always expecting JSON, but that's the kind of format that's often used in Rails if not mistaken.

If that doesn't work just use the `render json:` part as that is definitely a return.

**Update**
Further from our discussion it turns out that after making a robust Ajax call and tweaking the action, the final hurdle was a window.location that was not working. The cause of the problem was that location had been rebound to another function. All that needed to be done in the end is to rename that custom function and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: Hmmm... I can see that you're right, I'm not returning anything.  I'm actually new to Rails myself, I'll have to figure out how to do that.

Comment: Yes, so what you need to do here is send a response with an HTTP response code like 200 for success or 500 or  something else for failure. Then your AJAX will understand what happened behind the scenes - good or bad, and you can inform the user instead of making assumptions.

Comment: Wow, as you made the edit, I had done almost the same thing in my code!  Yours is a little nicer, though, so I'll borrow it... a console.log in the success condition showed the code triggered correctly all the way through, but the redirect still doesn't work!  Argh!

Comment: @skwidbreth please let me know your current status (I'm out for now)

Comment: Yes - thanks to your efforts, I was able to get it to work.  First of all, everything you showed me here was helpful and necessary, but the thing that got it working was when you suggested that I get the value of window.location before the AJAX call, which revealed that that value was being set in another part of my app by some geoLocation functionality.  All that it took to get it to run properly was me closing and reopening the window (agh!).  Please edit your answer to reflect this odd narrative, and that well-deserved green check is yours, friend.

Comment: Alright all done, the only problem is that updating the answer with this specific detail is valid but ironically a little off topic to your question as it may be unlikely that someone searching for future reference is going to have the same escalation in the problem described in your question. :P

Comment: Well, we can't all be perfect - I'll add some annotations to the question to try to clarify the situation for anyone who might stumble upon this.

Answer (score 1):

Add a datatype

```
$.ajax({
  url: "report/submission",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: 'json', #Add json data type, as we'll render json from controller
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content"))},
  data: {"report" : reportParameter},
  success: function(response) {
    console.log("Response is ", response);
    //When we get 200, this function should execute
    window.location.href = "/report/summary";
  },
  error: function(error){
    console.log("Error is ", error);
  }
});
```

And in the controller

```
def submission
  @incomingReport = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(params[:report])
  @newReportIDArray = Array.new
  @incomingReport.each do |x|
    hash = ActionController::Parameters.new(x)
    @new_report = Report.new(report_params(hash))
    @new_report.save
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { head :ok } #This will return 200 status back to ajax call
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you - I did end up adding the dataType and your controller code works in terms of generating the 200 status, but still no redirect!  I must be doing something else wrong...

Comment: Please add an error callback too, and console.log the success and error responses. See my update.

Comment: Check what gets printed on console.

Comment: I added the error condition, but nothing is printed to the console.

Comment: That's why we have the two strings "Response is", and "Error is". We can know in which function we are? Are you saying not even these two strings were printed?

Comment: For what it's worth, `window.open('/report/summary');` works - it opens the url in a new tab... but that's not what's needed here...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115563/discussion-between-kumar-and-skwidbreth).

Comment: thank you so much for your help - everything you told me to do was correct, the problem resulted from the fact that the window.location value was being set elsewhere in my app by geoLocaiton functionality - I had no idea that this could've been the cause. Jonathan was able to help me crack that last bit, but all of your advice is good and sound.

Comment: Awesome! Way to go!